# What pre-/post-treatment cohorts should I include in a generalised diff-in-diff with treatment on cohort level?

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, group-differences

I analyse an educational policy that shortened mandatory schooling. The rollout of the reform happened over 3 subsequent years in different states ($c=0$ is the last graduation cohort pre-reform, $c=3$ is the first graduation cohort in which every state has introduced short schooling). The treatment is thus assigned at the $state\times graduation\;cohort$ level and an individual characteristic constant over time (>no individual FE). I have panel data on individuals and want to estimate the following model:

$y_{ist}=\alpha_s + \beta_t + \gamma \times exp_i + \delta \times D_i + \epsilon_{ist}$

With $y_{ist}$ as outcome (log-wage), state $s$ and calendar year $t$ fixed effects and a treatment dummy $D_i$ indicating whether a person is part of a cohort with shorter schooling. $exp$ is an experience measure equal to the amount of years since graduation (I also include other covariates, but lets just assume for this question that the treatment effect is constant post graduation & similar for each of the three introductions & individuals do not differ systematically across treated/non-treated states).

My interpretation of the model is that it should estimate the average log-wage difference between the treated and non-treated graduation cohorts, e.i. comparing cohorts at $c=1$, $c=2$, ... (lets also ignore the most recent diff-in-diff literature and Bacon-Decompositions and such, this is something I will deal with once I have answered this question).

My question now is: What cohorts should I include in my estimation? I have data on graduation cohorts $c\in [-20, 10]$. However, the only cohorts with a "comparison" cohort are $c=1,2$. Intuitively I would include cohorts $c\in [0, 2]$, as this translates to the two diff-in-diff specifications one could isolate from the model. But I have the feeling that this does not use the data I have access to efficiently.